# How do I Prove (by induction) that the series $1^3+2^3+...+n^3=(1+2+...+n)^2$?

Tags: induction

This is a question from my textbook, it goes like this:

Prove (by induction) that the series $1^3+2^3+...+n^3=(1+2+...+n)^2$

**Here is my attempt at a solution:**

The base case would be: $n = 1 \implies 1^3=1^2$

Then we suppose that the statement works for a certain: $n=k$.

This gives us: $1^3+2^3+...+k^3=(1+2+...+k)^2$ (the inductive assumption) and this can be written as: $1^3+2^3+...+k^3=(\frac{k(k+1)}{2})^2$ by using the sum formula.

Further: $n=(k+1) \implies LHS = 1^3+2^3+...+k^3+(k+1)^3 =$ (by using the inductive assumption) $=(\frac{k(k+1)}{2})^2 +(k+1)^3$ and the $RHS = (1+2+...+k+(k+1))^2$

The proof would be complete if I could show that the $LHS = RHS$ but how do I do that?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not sure about the downvote... The question is clear and OP shows work. Still a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry for that! If someone would like to please help me with the last part of this question I would still appreciate that very much!

Comment: Write $1 + 2+...+k+(k+1)$ as $(1+2+...+k)+(k+1)$. Then when you square it, you'll get something of the form $a^2+2ab+ b^2$, where $a^2$ is the RHS of the inductive hypothesis. Not sure if that makes sense...!

Comment: Thank you! The question is solved, I am sorry for making a duplicate, should have been more thorough in my search before posting!

Comment: Duplicates are hard to avoid, and nothing to apologize for (usually)!